# Where did Open Table go in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

As of SQL Server 2005, you used to be able to open a flat file in SQL Management Studio off the right click menu for any database table. Once opened, you could add or update records right there in the grid.

Now that SQL Server 2008 is out, Microsoft has hidden that feature, at least from the right-click menu.

Where did it go?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's replaced by "Edit Top 200 Rows". You can change that command in the Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Commands.

But once you right-click a table, choose "Edit Top 200 Rows", hunt on the toolbar for a button called "Show SQL Pane". From here you can edit the query so the grid shows a subset of the data that you want.

They did this because people were accidentally opening huge tables with the old Open Table command. This method seems to work pretty well, though in general I find that the 2008 version is pretty wonky when talking to 2005 databases, but that's another matter....

Answer (score 13):

Changed the value in options to 0 and you can open the entire table.

Answer (score 7):

You could sett the default value of "Edit Top 200 Rows" too "0"

In the Tools Menu -> Options... under SQL server Object Explorer\Table and view options\Value Edit Top  Rows Command. Change the default value 200 too "0".

You should now have the option "Edit All Rows" instead of "Edit Top 200 Rows" as a default and if you know it is a laaarge table use the "Select Top 1000 Rows" as a rewiew of the table.